# Find the largest integer $n$ such that $10^n$ divides $10^6!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, factorial

Let $N=10^6!$

1. Find the largest integer $n$ such that $10^n$ divides $N$.
2. Furthermore, compute the first digit and the last non-zero digit of $N$.

I have some ideas that you should be able to use the factors 2 and 5 of 10 and modular arithmetic to solve it but I'm not really getting anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could show the work you did so that we can help you finish it?

Comment: Hint for 1: You can reduce the problem to finding $a$ where $a$ is the exponent of $5$ in the prime factorization of $10^6!$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you need to count how many powers of 10 you can form out of the prime factorization of N. You will have *many* more twos than fives (why?), so you just need to determine the exponent of 5 in the prime factorization of N.

To determine the exponent of 5 in the prime factorization, think about where the fives are going to come from: namely, multiples of 5. You'll have to be careful, though. Some multiples of 5 will contribute more fives than others...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand your hints. Could you explain further?

Comment: I'll do a different problem: Find the largest integer $n$ such that $10^n$ divides $25!$. I take it you understand why the exponent of 5 in the prime factorization of $25!$ will be greater than the exponent of 2. So let's just compute the exponent of 5. You will get factors of 5 from the multiples of 5: 5, 10, 15, 20, and 25. The first four of these contribute one five each to the prime factorization, but 25 contributes two fives. So the exponent of 5 in the prime factorization of $25!$ will be six. Hence the value of $n$ is 6.

Comment: typo: I meant the exponent of 5 will be LESS than the exponent of 2.

Comment: @symplectomorphic While the approach is fairly easy, I was thinking how would we solve it for the really big numbers like in here?

Comment: @tpb261: you must find the sum $\lfloor\frac{10^6}{5}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{10^6}{25}\rfloor+\cdots+\lfloor\frac{10^6}{5^6}\rfloor$. in the simpler problem, e.g., we have $\lfloor\frac{25}{5}\rfloor=5$ and $\lfloor\frac{25}{25}\rfloor=1$, giving $n=6$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Oh... Now I see it.. I was trying to compute the number of powers of 5 from numbers ending in 5 and number of powers of 10 from numbers ending in 0 and then add them - and got lost somewhere.